# With Sequelize, how do I find an entry in a table using a value contained in another table, with a single query?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

The following will use *valueA* to get an entry from a table containing *valueB*, which can then be used to get the desired entry from another table. How can I combine these sequential calls into a single call using Sequelize?

```
Client.find({where: {valueA: "1"}}).then((client)=> {
    User.find({where:{valueB: client.dataValues.valueB}}).then((user)=>{
        console.log(user);
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's done like this:

```
User.findOne({include: [{model: Client, where: {valueA: "1"}}]})
.then((entry)=> {
    // use db entry
});
```